# How to tag a "TS2531: Object is possibly 'null'" when the object is never null" error as a false positive?

Tags: typescript, compiler-errors

The following code

```
const infinoteUrl =
  $q.localStorage.getItem("infinote-dev-api") === null
    ? `${window.location.protocol}//${window.location.host}`
    : $q.localStorage.getItem("infinote-dev-api")
console.log(`infinote URL: ${infinoteUrl}`)

let infinoteToken = $q.localStorage.getItem("infinote-token")
if (infinoteToken === null && !infinoteUrl.toString().includes("localhost")) {
   ...
}
```

compiles with the `TS2531: Object is possibly 'null'` error:

```
TS2531: Object is possibly 'null'.
    106 |
    107 |     let infinoteToken = $q.localStorage.getItem("infinote-token")
  > 108 |     if (infinoteToken === null && !infinoteUrl.toString().includes("localhost")) {
        |                                    ^^^^^^^^^^^
    109 |       infinoteToken = "empty"
    110 |       $q.notify({
    111 |         message: 'no infinote-token in local storage',
```

I do not belive that `infinoteUrl` can ever be `null` so I would like to tell the compiler that this case is fine. Is there a way to do so?

As for the issue itself, I solved it thanks to [Optional Chaining](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html#optional-chaining) (`if (infinoteToken === null && !infinoteUrl?.toString().includes("localhost"))`), but **I am interested how to more generally tell the TS compiler that a case it detected is a false alert**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use `!` [non-null assertion operator](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-0.html#non-null-assertion-operator).

```ts
if (infinoteToken === null && !infinoteUrl!.toString().includes("localhost")) {
```

Answer (score 2):

You are assuming that `infinoteUrl` cannot be null, because you assume that `$q.localStorage.getItem("infinote-dev-api")` will return twice the same value. But there's no syntactical guarantee for that. Therefore TypeScript is warning you. You can use `!.` as suggested, but in my eyes, that defeats the point of using a strict type system in the first place. Try to leverage the features typescript has. You can rewrite it to

```
const maybeInfinoteUrl = $q.localStorage.getItem("infinote-dev-api");
const infinoteUrl =
   maybeInfinoteUrl === null
    ? `${window.location.protocol}//${window.location.host}`
    : maybeInfinoteUrl
console.log(`infinote URL: ${infinoteUrl}`)
```

or a much simpler form (which basically compiles to something similar) would be

```
const infinoteUrl =
  $q.localStorage.getItem("infinote-dev-api")
    ?? `${window.location.protocol}//${window.location.host}`

console.log(`infinote URL: ${infinoteUrl}`)
```

here you have a TypeScript Plaground example: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAcwKZQGoEMA2JUAUAlAFyJgg46IA+iAzlAE4xjKIDeAUIr4k+hBMkAciz0AJsBEBuLgF8uXCAkaIAHogC8KdNjyEi2rTopVEAfkQiAjgHdUTEYjJpMufMTkqwagJ7auu4GxJZWtg5OcsqqcDioAHQ4cMgE6glQcAAycJEAwuKGRN6x8UkpBH4Z2bmOBfRFMkA

Answer (score -1):

Use [`@ts-ignore`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-6.html#suppress-errors-in-ts-files-using--ts-ignore-comments)

```
// @ts-ignore TS2531: Object is possibly 'null'
if (infinoteToken === null && !infinoteUrl.toString().includes("localhost"))
```

This will ignore **all** errors on the line below the comment (so using optional chaining even though the value is never `null` will be safer)

Comment: Downvoting, `@ts-ignore` literally disables Typescript for the given line and never should be the solution.

Comment: @NoNameProvided: *never should be the solution* → the documentation states *we recommend you use this comments very sparingly* (and the feature exists in the first place)